# React hooks throttle on useLayoutEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following hook using `useLayoutEffect` to register an event listener on the resize event of the window.
I would like to add a throttle to it, say 1000ms, to call `handleCanvasResize` at most once per second.

What syntax should I use ?

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleCanvasResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleCanvasResize);
    };
  }, [handleCanvasResize]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function reference which is throttled and then add it as a listener for your resize event. You can either use a library for throttle or implement your own.

```
const handleCanvasResizeThrottled = useMemo(() => _.throttle(handleCanvasResize, 1000), []);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleCanvasResizeThrottled);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleCanvasResizeThrottled);
    };
  }, [handleCanvasResizeThrottled]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use useDebounce, this would work:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const [handleCanvasResizeDebounce] = useDebounce(handleCanvasResize, 1000);
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleCanvasResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleCanvasResizeDebounce);
    };
  }, [handleCanvasResize]);
```

Comment: Do you mean this implementation for instance ? https://dev.to/onygami/improve-performance-of-your-react-app-with-debouncing-build-your-own-usedebounce-hook-1fb1

Comment: I get the following error "React Hook "useDebounce" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function."

Comment: After googling more, I actuallly meant throttle and not debounce